# React hooks boolean in state not properly being set

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I apologize but I could not find an answer that helps with my problem.

I'm making a pokemon 20 questions game and recently added a new question to ask.

I'll do my best to keep it clear. But every answer is stored in state

Like this:

```
  const [type, setType] = useState(null);
  const [weakness, setWeakness] = useState(null);
  const [evolve, setEvolve] = useState(null);
```

etc.

So I have buttons set up that assign these values as a user progresses through the game.
But my evolve question breaks the game.

Here is the function

```
const evolveAssign = (canEvolveBoolean) => {
setEvolve(canEvolveBoolean); 
setPokemonData((prevPokeArray) => // pokemon data is a giant array of pokemon objects
  prevPokeArray.filter((pokemon) => {
    if (canEvolveBoolean === true) {
      return pokemon.prev_evolution || pokemon.next_evolution; //checks if the properties exist. Pokemon that do not evolve, do not have such properties.
    } else {
      return !pokemon.prev_evolution && !pokemon.next_evolution;
    }
  })
)};
```

This is how it is being returned. Which I admit, I'm not sure if this is the best way to display questions.

```
{type && weakness && !evolve && (
   <div>
      <strong>Can your Pokemon Evolve?</strong>
      <EvolveBtn mapEvolutions={mapEvolutions} onClick={evolveAssign} />
   </div>
)}
```

### The problem

When the user hits 'No' it will pass `false` to the function, and it does seem to work! But the question gets stuck **only on "No"** So I logged

```
<p>evolve = {evolve}</p>
```

and it will show 'evolve = '. So somehow, evolve is not being set at all? I haven't had this issue before with the other questions.

Is there something weird going on because it's a Boolean? Is my JS logic bad? I'm pretty much out of ideas. I apologize if this was unclear/messy. I'd love any feedback as I'm still learning.

Thank you very much.

EDIT: Created a Codesandbox here!

https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-bush-u6yel?file=/src/App.js

The error can be seen if you choose Bug -> Fire -> "No". It will break after that.

Comment: Your questions inside the `form`?

Comment: logging right after `setEvolve` will not show the updated value

Comment: @Ali Yaghoby no it's not inside form. Just divs.

Comment: @Ramesh Reddy I'm logging {evolve} in the return. Logging {type} or {weakness} will show a value. So I figured evolve should be 'true' or 'false' depending on what the user chooses.

Comment: @user15498557 Could you replicate the issue in a sandbox and add the link to the question? Some suggestions: `evolve`'s initial state can be `false` instead of `null`, `if (canEvolveBoolean === true)` can be simply `if (canEvolveBoolean)`, the parameter `canEvolveBoolean` can be renamed to `canEvolve`

Comment: @RameshReddy added a codesandbox in the update!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at the sandbox. Several things can be improved but I will just focus on the `evolve` issue.

In JavaScript `null` and `false` are falsy values. `!null` or `!false` will return `true`. This is why the questions are rendered incorrectly after selecting `evolve`.

A quick and easy fix would be to check if `evolve` is `null` or the opposite if the user already selected `evolve`.

```
{
    type && weakness && (evolve === null) && (
        <div style={{ fontSize: 50 }}>
            <strong>Can your Pokemon Evolve?</strong>
            <EvolveBtn mapEvolutions={mapEvolutions} onClick={evolveAssign} />
        </div>
    )
}

{/* What height? */ }
{
    type && weakness && (evolve !== null) && !height && (
        <div style={{ fontSize: 50 }}>
            <strong>Select Height</strong>
            <HeightBtn mapHeight={mapHeight} onClick={heightAssign} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Similar checks need to be used in the rest of the conditions if you simply want to make the app work.

Comment: Yep that'll do it! I should have realized null is a falsey value. I did go through and apply         {type !== null &&
          weakness !== null &&
          evolve !== null &&
          height !== null &&
          weight !== null
And the like. So now it works and I don't need to worry about this happening again in the future if I follow this pattern. Thank you very much!